# Accessing camera in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

**TL;DR: Doesn't work with IOS10 simulator. IOS9, however, seems fine.**

I've been trying to implement L Wansbrough's [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) module which everyone seems to recommend.  After 10 hours of failing to get it to work, I really really need some help.

I gave up trying to get it into my existing project, so for now I'm just trying to do this from scratch in a brand new area.  This is what I'm doing:

```
react-native init cameraProject
```

Okay, new project made.  Let's just make sure the versions are right:

```
react-native -v
```

I get `react-native-cli: 1.0.0 react-native: 0.36.0` returned. Just to check the requirements fully:

```
java -version
```

Returns: java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)

So the requirements look solid.  Now:

```
react-native run-ios
```

Success - the app runs in the simulator, everything works as it should.  Now I try and follow the documentation to install the react-native-camera.  First off, there's a new requirements section regarding iOS10 which my simulator is running.  You need to add the privacy key regarding the camera to the Info.plist file.  This seems to have been omitted from the source code's example Info file and the documentation doesn't have the code required.  I've dug around and added the following to `cameraProject/ios/cameraProject/Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Going to use some photos</string>
```

That's added in alphabetical order in the list, around line 25.  Refreshing simulator and it's all good.  Next:

```
npm install react-native-camera@https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git --save
```

followed by:

```
react-native link react-native-camera
```

Perfect; I get the messages I expect:

```
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-camera android dependency 
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-camera has been successfully linked 
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-camera ios dependency 
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-camera has been successfully linked
```

Everything still works as it should.  Onto the 'Usage' section. I'm going to copy and paste the code out from GitHub into a module called BadInstagramCloneApp.js  I'm then going to import that into index.ios.js with a basic `import BadInstagramCloneApp from './BadInstagramCloneApp';` and we'll stick it in the main body with `<BadInstagramCloneApp />`.

Refresh the simulator:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PummB.png)

Alright, so quit the simulator, close Terminal and re-run `react-native run-ios` as I believe that should rebuild.  It still doesn't work, throws:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.  Check the render method of 'cameraProject'.
```

I've loaded Xcode and looked at the manual instructions to link files.  My library folder has the `RCTCamera.xcodeproj` file already.  It's also already got `libRCTCamera.a` in the cameraProject->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries section. The Header Search Paths have the correct items in there and they are both marked as 'recursive' as per the instructions.  Then CMD+R to run the project.  New simulator loads, looks like it's going to work then falls over with the same red screen.  Quit Xcode, run `react-native run-ios` again from Terminal (says build succeeded) and it's still giving the same error as above.

I've tried every permutation of this I can think of. I've tried copying the code from inside the example files, I've tried the older version of the module and I've followed a couple of tutorials online which are supposed to launch the react-native-camera as well.  Not a single thing I've tried has ended in anything except a red screen or the application crashing out.

Suggestions?  All I want to do is allow the user to take a photo and then return that photo as a Base64 encoded object.

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import BadInstagramCloneApp from './BadInstagramCloneApp';

export default class cameraProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <BadInstagramCloneApp />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('cameraProject', () => cameraProject);
```

**BadInstagramCloneApp.js**

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

class BadInstagramCloneApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: '#000',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 40
  }
});

// AppRegistry.registerComponent('BadInstagramCloneApp', () => BadInstagramCloneApp);
// AppRegistry.registerComponent('cameraProject', () => BadInstagramCloneApp);
module.exports = (BadInstagramCloneApp);
```

The console.log then throws this:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:62Cannot read property 'Aspect' of undefinedhandleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:62handleError @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:120reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:30guardedLoadModule @ require.js:60_require @ require.js:49(anonymous function) @ require-0.js:1executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:20onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:38
RCTLog.js:38Running application cameraProject ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
ExceptionsManager.js:62Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:62handleError @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:120reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:30guard @ MessageQueue.js:48callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:107onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:44
ExceptionsManager.js:82Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'Aspect' of undefinedreactConsoleError @ ExceptionsManager.js:82logIfNoNativeHook @ RCTLog.js:38__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:236(anonymous function) @ MessageQueue.js:108guard @ MessageQueue.js:46callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:107onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:44
ExceptionsManager.js:82Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

If I quit everything, reload, rebuild using `react-native run-ios` then the project builds correctly but crashes out after the splash screen is displayed.  Console doesn't log any errors, but if I choose 'Pause on all caught exceptions' from the dev tools then it shows a stop here:

```
**_nodeUtil.js**
/** Used to access faster Node.js helpers. */
var nodeUtil = (function() {
  try {
    return freeProcess && freeProcess.binding('util');
  } catch (e) {}
}());
```

If I try and run in from within Xcode rather than Terminal then it builds correctly, the simulator launches, but inside Xcode it opens cameraProject->Libraries->RCTCamera.xcodeproj->RCTCameraManager.m and highlights line 988:

```
[self.session commitConfiguration]; <Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50)
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: should post your full code of camera component.

Comment: You're right. Amended as suggested.

Comment: module.exports = (BadInstagramCloneApp ); badInstagramCloneApps.js instead of AppRegistry.registerComponent('BadInstagramCloneApp', () => BadInstagramCloneApp);

Comment: That's certainly made a difference; as soon as you launch the app the simulator quits and returns to the home screen. I've tried quitting the simulator and re-running react-native run-ios from the terminal and the build succeeds but the app still immediately crashes and exits to the home screen.

Comment: check console logs issue must be written there.

Comment: Tried reloading multiple time with the debugger window open in Chrome, but nothing logged to the console at all; just loads, shows splash screen and quits. :(

Comment: try without aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill} and remove  justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center', from container style and read requirements in this page https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera. I use this component as well and it works well.

Comment: I updated my version of JDK as per the requirements as you suggested. I then deleted the entire cameraProject folder, and started again following the same steps. This time, I do get some console.log errors after I make the change to the module.exports line; I've updated the code to reflect this.  

The console logs are shown above.  Thank you for your help so far, especially as you say you've got this module to work in the past.  Does my code run on your machine?

Comment: This looks like an issue with IOS10 simulator (not sure about the real hardware).  I've installed IOS9 and the camera appears to work!  12 hours to figure that one out...

Comment: It writes on main page under requirements at top anyway you must have learned a lot while looking for issue.

Comment: Yeah, learned a lot - and it doesn't say anywhere anything about not working with IOS10; the only mention is the Privacy key which I added (noted in main code) but that doesn't appear to solve the issue!

Comment: yes, you're right i missed that point

Answer (score 0):

If I quit everything, reload, rebuild using `react-native run-ios`, then
the project builds correctly but crashes out after the splash screen
is displayed. Console doesn't log any errors, but if I choose 'Pause
on all caught exceptions' from the dev tools then it shows a stop
here:

**_nodeUtil.js**

> Used to access faster Node.js helpers.

```
var nodeUtil = (function() {   
    try {
      return freeProcess && freeProcess.binding('util');   
    } catch (e) {} 
 }());
```

I just can tell you that this is not relevant for your question, it always happen. Look here:
[React Native - debugging exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620483/react-native-debugging-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with a project I'm working on. According to [this gitHub issue](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/386), the problem is a combination of new iOS 10 camera permissions and possibly also a problem with the simulator camera support itself. I've found that if I open the xcodeproj file directly in XCode, the simulator opens fine. I still haven't found a permanent fix but running build from XCode instead of `react-native run-ios` bypasses the issue for me. I'll follow up if I find a better option.

Comment: Tried this in XCode. Build failed. Got 27 errors all related to RCTCamera. Reset the cache as well with nothing.