# React Native - debugging exception

Tags: react-native, lodash

I'm using chrome to debug react native.
When I choose "Pause On Caught Exceptions" under "source" debugging tab, the following exception always occur: `TypeError: freeProcess.binding is not a function`

The file in which the exception occurs:

`http://localhost:8081/< Project_folder >/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/lodash/_nodeUtil.js`

The exception is in line 18:
`return freeProcess && freeProcess.binding('util');`

Full code on that .js page:

```
var freeGlobal = require('./_freeGlobal');

/** Detect free variable `exports`. */
var freeExports = typeof exports == 'object' && exports && !exports.nodeType && exports;

/** Detect free variable `module`. */
var freeModule = freeExports && typeof module == 'object' && module && !module.nodeType && module;

/** Detect the popular CommonJS extension `module.exports`. */
var moduleExports = freeModule && freeModule.exports === freeExports;

/** Detect free variable `process` from Node.js. */
var freeProcess = moduleExports && freeGlobal.process;

/** Used to access faster Node.js helpers. */
var nodeUtil = (function() {
  try {
    return freeProcess && freeProcess.binding('util');
  } catch (e) {}
}());

module.exports = nodeUtil;
```

What is the most elegant way to avoid this exception?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be syntax error. Try to make `Stop Remote JS Debugging` and `Reload`.

Comment: I didn't understand, how can it be a syntax error? I didn't write this code, it's a built in library...

I've tried stopping remote js debugging and reloading - doesn't solve this.
I think it has something to do with node.js, but I don't use node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've solved it temporarily.

I've changed line 18 to:

```
return freeProcess && (typeof freeProcess.binding === "function") && freeProcess.binding('util');
```

in this file:

```
/< Project_folder >/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/lodash/_nodeUtil.js
```

This solution is not the best, because it should be fixed in the git of the library. I think the library is lodash, but I couldn't find the file in its git - https://github.com/lodash/lodash